# Android command has been deprecated

Tags: android, macos, uiautomatorviewer

I have installed SDK Manager and set my environment variable.When I type in android in command line. It say android command has been deprecated. How do I launch uiautomatorviewer in Mac ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the deprecated from uiautomatorviewer, now you must use **monitor**.

See the documentation for more information
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html

Comment: I couldn't get it to work after I navigated to android-sdk/tools/

Comment: Here are the path I have set below. Can someone please advise on how to get  uiautomator to work on Mac.  Thanks

export JAVA_HOME=$(/Users/ade/Documents/java_home) PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME export M2_HOME=/Users/ade/Documents/apache-maven-3.5.2 export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin ANDROID_HOME=/users/ade/Library/Android/sdk export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Comment: That is deprecated too now

Answer (score 0):

You can launch uiautomatorviewer by typing `uiautomatorviewer` command in Terminal. uiautomatorviewer shell script located in **$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin** directory.

Comment: It do work on mine Mac. did you check $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin folder?   is uiautomatorviewer file in $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin folder?

Comment: I have added the path to include bin and below is what I got when I I typed uiautomatorviewer in terminal. Last login: Thu Dec 28 12:56:14 on ttys001
Ades-MBP:~ ade$ uiautomatorviewer
-Djava.ext.dirs=/users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Ades-MBP:~ ade$

Comment: OK, you can try just double click uiautomatorviewer file which located in $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin folder to open it. I guess there is something wrong with your android classpath configuration, so there is some error logs in Terminal when you type  uiautomatorviewer command.

Comment: Here is what I get when I clicked on it - Last login: Fri Dec 29 08:07:27 on ttys000
Ades-MBP:~ ade$ /Users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer ; exit;
-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: try type this command **`uiautomatorviewer -classpath /users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86‌​_64:/users/ade/Libra‌​ry/Android/sdk/tools‌​/lib`** in Terminal, hope it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162149/discussion-between-will-tang-and-tutuade).

Comment: it still didn't work . -Djava.ext.dirs=/users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/users/ade/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Ades-MBP:~ ade$ 
Thanks